# a problem creating a restore point in a restore point collection

Tags: azure, api, rest, azure-rest-api

I am trying to send the rest request to create a restore point in an existing restore point collection.
the request body is empty as i want to use default values and the uri is in the format of:

[https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{ResourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/restorePointCollections/{RestorePointCollectionName}/restorePoints/{RestorePointName}?api-version=2022-08-01](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%7BsubscriptionId%7D/resourceGroups/%7BResourceGroupName%7D/providers/Microsoft.Compute/restorePointCollections/%7BRestorePointCollectionName%7D/restorePoints/%7BRestorePointName%7D?api-version=2022-08-01).

I receive the following response:

*statusCode: 400, HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 158
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Fri, 06 Jan 2023 11:26:42 GMT
Expires: -1
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0, Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
x-ms-correlation-request-id: XXX
x-ms-ratelimit-remaining-resource: Microsoft.Compute/CreateRestorePoints3Min;119,Microsoft.Compute/CreateRestorePoints30Min;596
x-ms-ratelimit-remaining-subscription-writes: 1197
x-ms-request-id: XXX
x-ms-routing-request-id: XXX
{
**"error": {
"code": "InvalidParameter",
"message": "Required parameter 'RestorePoint' is missing (null).",
"target": "RestorePoint"
}**
}*

I did not manage to find any reference to this invalid argument in the available documentation at:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/restore-points/create?tabs=HTTP

any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

ok. so it seems that even though the body of the request is optional, you need to add an empty properties json object to have the request accepted...